# Receiving MMS messages using Twilio PHP MediaUrl

Tags: php, twilio

I am having trouble with the $_REQUEST['MediaUrl'] parameter that Twilio sends when making the post. It is saying the $_REQUEST['NumMedia'] == 1, but nothing is in there.

`strlen($_REQUEST['MediaUrl']) == 0`

I check my account and the image is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Because there can be multiple media urls in a given message, the [Media Url parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) are appended with an index number, eg `MediaUrl{N}`:

```
strlen($_REQUEST['MediaUrl0']) == 0

strlen($_REQUEST['MediaUrl1']) == 0

strlen($_REQUEST['MediaUrl2']) == 0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I love Twilio and have incorporated SMS to allow people to post info to my site. With MMS now, I look forward to creating a photo album.